# Block developers from forcing the build in Cruise control

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, cctray

We have configured the Cruisecontrol for our project and all developers can check the build result using Dashborad and CCTray.

we working on multisite projects so dont want the build should be handled by developer as we have seperate continous integration. I was just curious if we can block a group of users from forcing the build. So we want the builds should be forced by build master and not be developers. Developers can just see the build result.

How can we do that?

Comment: Why don't you trust your developers to do this?

Comment: Have you tried just asking them not to?

Answer (score 2):

Set `forceBuild="Deny"` in the `RolePermission` tag.  See the [CruiseControl documentation](http://build.nauck-it.de/doc/CCNET/Role%20Permission.html) for more information.